# Accumulators in haskell

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

In Haskell, if I write

```
 fac n = facRec n 1
   where facRec 0 acc = acc
         facRec n acc = facRec (n-1) (acc*n)
```

and compile it with GHC, will the result be any different than if I used

```
 fac 0 = 1
 fac n = n * fac (n-1)
```

I could easily do `fac n = product [1..n]` and avoid the whole thing, but I'm interested in how an attempt at tail recursion works out in a lazy language. I get that I can still get a stack overflow because thunks are building up, but does anything actually happen differently (in terms of the resulting compiled program) when I use an accumulator than when I just state the naive recursion? Is there any benefit to leaving out the tail recursion other than improved legibility? Does the answer change at all if I'm using `runhaskell` to run the computation instead of compiling it first?

Comment: What is your definition of "does anything actually happen differently"? The trivial answer is "yes", because they _are_ different - one is tail recursive, and the other isn't. But I don't think that's what you're asking..?

Comment: don't you mean facRec n acc = facRec (n-1) (acc*n) ????

Comment: @lijie - I'm mainly interested in whether GHC does tail call optimization (with or without the accumulator), but I left it general because I'm honestly not sure how tail recursion interacts with lazy languages, and it may do other different things based on my using one form vs another. I don't know what those other things are.

Comment: @David V. - Ugh. Yup. Fixed. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I think it would be safe to say that all functional language interpreters/compilers/whatever-runs-the-code implement tail call optimization. but yes the interaction of accumulators and laziness is irritating...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tail recursion *does* make sense in (GHC) Haskell if your accumulator is strict.  To demonstrate the problem, here is a "trace" of your tail-recursive definition of `fac`:

```
   fac 4
~> facRec 4 1
~> facRec 3 (1*4)
~> facRec 2 ((1*4)*3)
~> facRec 1 (((1*4)*3)*2)
~> facRec 0 ((((1*4)*3)*2)*1)
~> (((1*4)*3)*2) * 1
  ~> ((1*4)*3) * 2
    ~> (1*4) * 3
      ~> 1*4
    ~> 4 * 3
  ~> 12 * 2
~> 24 * 1
~> 24
```

The indentation level corresponds (roughly) to stack level.  Note that the accumulator is only evaluated at the very end, and that may cause a stack overflow.  The trick, of course, is to make the accumulator strict.  It's theoretically possible to show that facRec is strict if it is called in a strict context, but I am not aware of any compiler that does that, ATM.  GHC *does* do tail call optimisation, though, so the `facRec` calls use constant stack space.

For the same reason `foldl'` is usually preferred over `foldl`, since the former is strict in the accumulator.

Regarding your second part, `runhaskell`/`runghc` is just a wrapper over GHCi.  If GHCi finds compiled code it will use that, otherwise it will use the bytecode interpreter which performs few optimisations, so don't expect any fancy optimisations to happen.

Comment: The `foldl'` vs `fold` hint helped, I think; http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27. In other words, if I wanted tail recursion in the sense I'm used to from Scheme, I'd have to say something like `let acc' = acc * n in seq acc' $ facRec (n-1) acc'` instead of `facRec (n-1) (acc*n)` on the last line of `facRec`.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Yep; or, more simply, you can write `fracRec (n-1) $! acc*n`, where `$!` is just strict function application (`f $! x = x \`seq\` f x`).

Comment: The easiest way to add strictness is to use `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}`.  Then you have strict pattern matches.  E.g., `let !x = ... in ...` or directly in the function definition: `facRec 0 !n = ...`

Answer (score 3):

In haskell, it only helps to write your program in a tail-recursive way if your accumulator is strict and you need to whole result.

With ghc's runHaskell the program won't be optimised, so there won't be a strictness analysis, so you may stack overflow; while if you compile with optimisations the compiler may detect the accumulator needs to be strict and optimise accordingly.

To see how things happen differently (or not) the best way is to inspect the core langage generated, [a good blog post from Don Stewart explains things](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/haskell-as-fast-as-c-working-at-a-high-altitude-for-low-level-performance/) . Many of his blog post are interesting if your interested about performance, by the way.

Comment: Also facRec probably should be in a where clause rather than a top level declaration. This is a worker-wrapper transformation and it is more likely to be noticed by the strictness analyser.

Comment: @stephen - fixed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't complete.  I assume you mean GHC, and at least without optimizations the answer is "yes" because the worker function (`facRec` in the first or `fac` in the second) has an arity 2 compared to one and the assembly will reflect this.  With optimizations or with JHC the answer is probably "no".

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm talking about the GHC; amended the question.